# Input in menu item?

Tags: cocoa, nstextfield, nsmenuitem

I would like to know if it is possible to have a NSTextField (for example) as a menu item in a menu. Your help will be very appreciated!

Sweet day,
—Albé

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spotlight does it, though I think they're cheating and using a custom view that looks like a menu rather than an actual menu.